# How can I do a new translation of vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, translation

I will try contribuite to the vscode project and I would like submit a new translation.
How I do this? Is there any tool that is used in the project?

Sorry for my english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taken from the [VSCode Wiki](https://github.com/Microsoft/Localization/wiki/How-to-request-a-new-UI-language-for-VS-Code-project)

Step and criteria:

1. Request a new language in transifex if not available yet.
   Create a request through issue report page of vscode github project. Click "New Issue" button. Suggest put '[loc]Request to add xxx language to VS Code' in title.
2. At least 3 contributors vote in the request. Record transifex user name in the request.
3. After reach 3 votes, project team will make a decision. If approved, will make the language available in transifex in one week.
4. After translation coverage reach 35%, use same request to track adding language to VS Code product.
5. If after 6 months, translation coverage doesn't reach 90%, language will be removed from VS Code product.